# Attempts to pay through paypal result in 'this invoice has already been paid'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, nopcommerce

Using NopCommerce 3.00.

When checking out in the shopping cart, with no shipping cost being added, and a subtotal, an order is generated and saved in the local NopCommerce database.

The proceed to payment redirects to Paypal (currently the PayPal sandbox), which allows the user to sign in and pay.

After signing in and choosing a payment method, the user click the 'pay now' button and is redirected to a message 'This invoice has already been paid' on the PayPal side.

In the Nop db, there is a unique order ID being generated, and I changed the auto_increment seed to be a high number such that there's no possibility of collision of order IDs from previous testing.

I also enabled the option within PayPal under 'Profile' to allow receiving payments multiple times for the same invoice id.

Any ideas based on NopCommerce or other payment gateway integration with PayPal?

Does NopCommerce post a different invoice ID than the internally-stored order ID?